# Facebook notifications

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

There are a lot of SO questions around facebook notifications, but I dont seem to be able to get a strait answer out of them.

I want to build a canvas app, that the user can authorise for notifications. Essentially, I want my app to have server side messages pushed to users of the facebook app.

I used the Graph API explorer, and I tried to send a notification request to:

```
100001564481290/notifications
```

but I got an error:

```
{
    "error": {
    "message": "(#3) App must be on whitelist",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 3
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to get past this, a lot of googling suggests that you cannot send notifications through the graph API, but I would like a definitive answer on the topic.

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Try this this should fix it:

Click 'edit settings'.
Go to 'Advanced'.
Find a small box labelled 'Server Whitelist'.
Enter the NUMERICAL IP address of your server."

ps: You have to be at your app page meaning at developers.facebook.com

Comment: thanks, Ill give this a try! can I do this on the graph API explorer?